# How to extend a struct in SWIG with a static variable, with a custom getter and setter?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I want to wrap a static member variable of a struct, such that when it is read or written from Python, a custom get/set function is called on the C++ side. The following works, for a non-static variable. This is `foo.h`:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  static int bar() { std::cout << "Foo::bar()\n"; return 0; }
};

#endif
```

`foo.i` looks as follows:

```
%module foo
%{
  #include "foo.h"
%}

struct Foo
{
};

%extend Foo {
  int i;
}

%{
  int Foo_i_get(Foo* obj) {
    return Foo::bar();
  }
  void Foo_i_set(Foo* obj, int i) {}
%}
```

This sort of works, in Python I can do:

```
import foo
f = foo.Foo()
f.i
```

This triggers `Foo::bar()` being called. What I want to achieve is the following having the same behavior:

```
import foo
foo.Foo.i
```

This does not work, since `i` is not a class property.
I naively tried changing the following in the `.i` file:

```
%extend Foo {
  static int i;
}
```

This gives compilation errors in the following wrapper code generated by SWIG:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *Swig_var_Foo_i_get(void) {
  PyObject *pyobj = 0;

  pyobj = SWIG_From_int((int)(Foo::i));
  return pyobj;
}
```

This is the error message given by `g++`:

```
foo_wrap.c: In function ‘PyObject* Swig_var_Foo_i_get()’:
foo_wrap.c:3208:31: error: ‘i’ is not a member of ‘Foo’
    pyobj = SWIG_From_int((int)(Foo::i));
```

So obviously this is not the right approach. How can I extend a struct with a static variable, with custom setters and getters?

Comment: Even without `%extend` SWIG doesn't actually make the static members of  a class accessible through the `foo.Foo.i` syntax. We can do something with some workaround I'm sure, but it won't be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

this might work: foo.i looks as follows:

```
%module foo
%{
  #include "foo.h"
%}

%include "foo.h"

%extend Foo {
  int get_i(){ return Foo::bar(); }
  %pythoncode %{
     i = property(get_i)
  %}
}
```

Comment: Long time ago I needed this, I'm not sure how and whether I found a solution in the end. I'll make a note and check how I solved it; and whether your approach works, thanks for the belated answer!